# Chrome.tabs.executeScript() and file included

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to develop a simple Chrome extension, in which I need to 'listen' to the various AJAX calls made inside the page.

This is the code i used for listening AJAX calls :

```
var isAjaxWorking = false;
//timeout
var timeout;

//create new AJAX listener
var s_ajax = new Object();

//rewrite send() method XMLHttpRequest
s_ajax.tempSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;

s_ajax.callback = function (event){
   isAjaxWorking = true;
   timeout = 500;//5 seconds
   var cycle = setInterval(function(){
      timeout--;
      if(timeout > 0){
         if(event.readyState === 4){
            isAjaxWorking = false;
            clearInterval(cycle);
         }
       }
       else{
        console.log('s_ajax.callback : timeout');
        clearInterval(cycle);
        isAjaxWorking = null;
      }
   },10);
}

XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function(a,b) {
   if (!a) var a='';
   if (!b) var b='';
   s_ajax.tempSend.apply(this, arguments);
   s_ajax.callback(this);
}
```

If I inject this directly inside the console of the page I want to listen, it works like a charm, but when I try to execute this using `chrome.tabs.executeScript()` inside my chrome extension it is like everything is deleted just after the script is executed. I know this is probably something terribly simple , but I'm not able to solve this. Thanks in advance for every tip

Comment: Can you include how you use `chrome.tabs.executeScript` at Question ? What do you mean by "everything is deleted" ?

Comment: There is an API specifically made to listen to network requests, why not just use that? https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest

Comment: @guest271314 I just use it like in every example you find on the Internet; by the way I think that the problem is what james Dewes has pointed out in the first answer: my overwrite does not affect the method in the page because my code is not interacting with the page's code

Comment: @BeardFist I think this could be the right workaround.. I'll give it a try, thanks man!

Comment: @Alessandro _"I just use it like in every example you find on the Internet"_ Can you include `js` of the example that you are using at Question ? _"by the way I think that the problem is what james Dewes has pointed out in the first answer: my overwrite does not affect the method in the page because my code is not interacting with the page's code"_ Is Question is resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this was driving me mad the other day. Have a read of this:

Isolated worlds allow each content script to make changes to its JavaScript environment without worrying about conflicting with the page or with other content scripts. For example, a content script could include JQuery v1 and the page could include JQuery v2, and they wouldn't conflict with each other.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Your code does not interact with the code in the page, so your overwrite of the cross domain request method  in your extension code will do nothing to the method used by the page.